# Using Hibernate in JBDS/JBoss Tools

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I'm new to jboss developer studio.

I'm trying to learn from a tutorial site and i'm stuck at a creating `SessionFactory` Object.

```
//creating configuration object  
Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file  

//creating session factory object  
SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  

//creating session object  
Session session=factory.openSession();  

//creating transaction object  
Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
```

I can't seem to import `SessionFactory` Class. The *JBoss EAP 6.1+ Runtime* library only contains 2 jars related to hibernate, `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.ja`r and `hibernate-validator-4.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar`.

I'm really having a hard time learning hibernate. I can't find a tutorial for developing web apps using `JBDS`.

Thank you in advance!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss 6.1 is sort of in a league of it's own and doesn't have the greatest support behind it.  I'd recommend avoiding it if you can and either moving up to Wildfly or back down to JBoss 5.

That being said, the JARs you see there only support JPA, not core Hibernate.  You don't have `SessionFactory` in strict JPA; those are replaced with `EntityManager` instances instead.  You'll either need to include the hibernate-core library in an EAR or add it to the JBoss libraries to use it.